# Asynchronous client socket - construct back the byte array

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, arrays

Question: I would like to know how to get all data from a stream.

I am sending data from Asynchronous Client Socket's `BeginSend` method to the `BeginReceive` method on the client's side. The goal now is to get all the bytes passed over the stream.

I have created a `StateObject` class, which includes a buffer field type of `byte[]`, and it has a fixed length (currently set to 2048).

So how can I pass the retrieved bytes to this field? Keep in mind that the data is coming in pieces, not all at once.

I have to construct all the bytes back as they were sent from server.

Can I use the `Array.Copy()` or `Buffer.BlockCopy` method, will it do the job?

The point is I have to consider multiple conditions:

- lets asume that all the indexes of buffer[2048] are set to 0
- in 1st copying starting index will  be 0 (then add the bytes get from the stream)
- in all next copyings the starting index must the the 1st zero in the array (or said with other words, the sum all all previous bytes copyed to array - 1).

How to achive that?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you get ReadCallback fired you have >0 byte in buffer (otherwise connection is broken) and number of actual bytes received in this data chunk. Every new data chunk starts from index 0 in your buffer.
Use `var message = new MemoryStream()` and than `message.Write(buffer,0, bytes_received)`on every read callback until you have all the data received. This will be the fastest way.